# Projection of bosonic and fermionic creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, second-quantization

For the creation and annihilation operator $a(\varphi)$ and $a^\dagger(\varphi)$ and the orthogonal projections i would like to understand why the following holds
\begin{equation}
    P_\pm a(\varphi) P_\pm = a(\varphi) P_\pm \,\neq \,P_\pm a(\varphi)
\end{equation}
and

\begin{equation}
    P_\pm a^\dagger(\varphi) P_\pm  = P_\pm a^\dagger(\varphi) \neq \,a^\dagger(\varphi) P_\pm
\end{equation}

I know how $a(\varphi)$ and $a^\dagger(\varphi)$ are defined, but I am not sure how to the projection operators act on them.

Edit: We defined the projection operators in the following way:
\begin{equation}
    P_+ := \frac{1}{N!} \sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_N} U_\sigma \quad\text{and}\quad P_- := \frac{1}{N!} \sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_N} \text{sgn}(\sigma) U_\sigma
\end{equation}
and annihilation and creation operator as
\begin{equation}
    (a^\dagger(\varphi)\Psi)_N := \sqrt{N}\varphi\otimes \psi_{N-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    (a(\varphi)\Psi)_N := \sqrt{N+1}\langle \varphi, \psi_{N+1}\rangle_1
\end{equation}

Comment: I think you  need to define your $P_\pm$.  There are many projection operators out there!

Comment: you are absolutely right, i added it

Comment: You should maybe also add the definition of creation/annihilation that you are using

Comment: i did, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the range of $P_\pm a^\dagger(\varphi)$ is a subspace of the (anti)-symmetric states (who are stable under $P_\pm$), while this is not true of $a^\dagger(\varphi)P_\pm $. For example, if $\psi\neq \varphi$ is another $1$-particle state, then :
$$a^\dagger(\varphi)P_\pm \psi =a^\dagger(\varphi) \psi  = \sqrt{2} \varphi \otimes \psi$$

is not symmetric.

To prove the other part, let $\psi_0,\psi_1,\ldots, \psi_n$ be $1$-particle states. Then :

\begin{align}
P_\pm a^\dagger(\psi_0) P_\pm \psi_1 \otimes \ldots \psi_n &= \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)!n!}\sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_{n+1}} \sum_{\sigma' \in \mathfrak S_n}\varepsilon^\pm(\sigma)\varepsilon^\pm(\sigma')U_\sigma  (\psi_0 \otimes \psi_{\sigma'(1)} \otimes \ldots \psi_{\sigma'(n)}) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)!n!}\sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_{n+1}}  \varepsilon^\pm(\sigma\circ\sigma') (\psi_{\sigma(0)} \otimes \psi_{\sigma\circ\sigma'(1)} \otimes \ldots \psi_{\sigma\circ\sigma'(n)}) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_{n+1}} \sum_{\sigma' \in \mathfrak S_n} \varepsilon^\pm(\sigma) (\psi_{\sigma(0)} \otimes \psi_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \ldots \psi_{\sigma(n)}) \\
&= P_\pm a^\dagger(\psi_0) \psi_1 \otimes \ldots \psi_n
\end{align}

where we consider $\sigma' \in \mathfrak S_n \subset \mathfrak S_{n+1}$ by setting $\sigma'(0)=0$.

The results for $a(\varphi)$ are just the adjoint of the ones for $a^\dagger(\varphi)$.

Comment: thank you very much!